# creating a webservice api for mobile contacts to save on server and retrieve in json

Tags: php, web-services

I am trying to create **web services(api)** in which i want to retrieve all contacts form mobile and save it on database(my own server).  Can anyone help me that how can i create it?

Comment: Provide some more information. What you have tried and in which case are you facing any issue.

Comment: Thanks.  I want to retrieve all contacts in array in json format by api.